# Darcy to SI permeation units

Tags: measurements, mathematics, unit

How can permeation units in Darcy be converted to the SI form. For example, how would 9.0 x 10-6 darcy be converted to SI units of permeation? How would it also be converted to the permeation units: (cm^3 . mm)/m^2 . d . atm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert [darcy units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_(unit)) to SI units

> ... 1 darcy is equivalent to 9.869233×10−13 m² or 0.9869233 (µm)². This conversion is usually approximated as 1 (µm)².[3] Note that this is the reciprocal of 1.013250—the conversion factor from atmospheres to bars.
>
> Specifically in the hydrology domain, permeability of soil or rock may also be defined as the flux of water under hydrostatic pressure (~ 0.1 bar/m) at a temperature of 20°C. In this specific setup, 1 darcy is equivalent to 0.831 m/day.

Comment: And the source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_(unit)#Conversions  -1 for not mentioning the source. I mean why should the community do **all of the work**?   originally the wiki is a community. and now we have to add in the details. you just did is copy paste. which is not expected on this site

Comment: @SolarMike: Click on the link. That's what it's for.

Comment: Shame someone lacks the knowledge of Darcys and microdarcys ...

Comment: @SolarMike If you know Darcys your mother will never forgive you;  if you don't know Darcys your father never will forgive you.

Comment: Yeah and I knew Darcys... and provided good info to loose points.

Answer (score 2):

For your question, 1 m2 = 10^12 Darcy.

For the next question, I think your question is units involved in Darcy's Law, i.e., the Darcy's units and SI units.

In general, we define the permeability of porous media as 1 Darcy, it means the porous media can transmit 1 cm3/s of water with viscosity of 1 cP (1 mPas) under pressure gradient of 1 atm/cm cross an area of 1 cm2. The units involved here are called Darcy's units.

For SI unit, we use flow rate of m3/s, viscosity of Pas, pressure of Pa, length of m, cross section area of m2, and we can get the permeability unit with m2.

If we use the units system for both cases, Darcy's equation is the same without any conversion factor.